# OpenGL - How can I rotate an object on the global axis?

Tags: opengl, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I'm trying to rotate an object along the global axis according to keyboard input. My current function works, but the consecutive rotations are done on the rotated axis instead of the global axis. I know the solution involves manipulating the matrices but I'm still learning and don't know what I need to do.

I've tried using glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix, but I think somewhere I'm missing the matrix multiplication.

```
def Render(screen):
    global _current
    global _pos
    global _angles

    m = glGetDouble(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)

    glTranslate(*_pos)

    glRotatef(_angles[0], 1, 0, 0)
    glRotatef(_angles[1], 0, 1, 0)
    glRotatef(_angles[2], 0, 0, 1)

    _current.Render(screen)
    glLoadMatrixf(m)
```

Comment: if you are still learning please  learn the modern way to do so.

Comment: https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/OpenGL

Comment: For local rotation you first apply rotation than position , for global you first apply position and than rotation.

Comment: Pleas specify what you mean by *"global axis"*